# Custom EditText in Android with separated bottom lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to make EditText with separated bottom lines looks like in the image below [image: The EditText]

I tried to put EditText and four ImageView into RelativeLayout.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_code"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@null"                                   
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"

                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is very bad solution because in small screens numbers begin to move out.

Comment: You can make selector file in drawable folder and apply to your edittext as a background.

Comment: I think may be create four edittext and automatically move cursor to next edittext.

Comment: It will not go automaic. You must apply `imeOptions` with `actionNext` after fill one edittext.

Comment: @AdamLuisSean  why you need seperate line because there is already line  in edittext by default.

Comment: Aashvi 2, If use many edittext then true, but I think separate lines in one edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input) library.

As its GitHub page says:

> ```
> <com.github.glomadrian.codeinputlib.CodeInput
> android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> app:underline_color="#457ad1"
> app:underline_selected_color="#9e1ace"
> app:text_color="#b12eff"
> app:hint_color="#77ce9d"
> app:hint_text="Pin code"
> app:codes="4"
> />
> ```

Add in dependencies

> ```
> compile 'com.github.glomadrian:CodeInput:1.1@aar'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

For this you require to add four edittext each with width = "0dp" and weight = "1" inside linearlayout with horizontal orientation. Something like this

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
>
   <Edittext 
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     .... add other required attributes
   />
<Edittext 
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     .... add other required attributes
   />
<Edittext 
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     .... add other required attributes
   />
<Edittext 
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     .... add other required attributes
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is only for illustration you will require to implement it your way with your required style and attributes.**